# How to run script post build on buildkite

Tags: continuous-integration

I have a clean up script I like to run post job on my buildkite pipeline. It should only be run when the job completes. What is the best way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the exact use case for Buildkite Post Command hook.
https://buildkite.com/docs/agent/v3/hooks#available-hooks